# How can my organization become a Root CA?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I'm the founder of a little non-profit French organization.

Currently, we're providing free web and shell hosting.

Is there a way to become a Trusted Certificate Authority, in order to give free SSL certificates to my customers, and also to avoid being an intermediate (and pay a lot for that), and/or avoid paying a lot for each certificate?

Comment: It is not hard to become a Certificate Authority. The tricky part is Trusted.

Comment: Exactely =) and the question is how to become trusted ^^ - Any idea?

Comment: [How to become an internationally recognized certificate authority (CA)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57266/how-to-become-an-internationally-recognized-certificate-authority-ca)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect you will find that it is too expensive to do so in terms of auditing requirements. Also, there is no single definition of what it means to be trusted. Each application is free to define their own trust, and to use their own root certificates. Practically speaking, you may only care about getting your CA certificate in the Windows root certificate program, in the Mozilla program, in the Java cacerts file, Opera, and maybe a few smaller ones. I think Chrome uses either Windows root certs or the Mozilla root certs.

Mozilla just issued a new [policy for CAs](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/policy/).

Here a few link to articles about Microsoft's program:
[Microsoft Root Certificate Program](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx)
[Windows root certificate program members](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125)
[Microsoft Root Certificate Program Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995347.aspx)

Here is an [article](http://www.opera.com/docs/ca/) on getting into Opera's root certificates.

Comment: Here is Apple's policy too: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ca_program.html

Comment: This answer only suggests irrelevant information and dosen't answers the real question.

Comment: @Cyborg: Oh, do tell us, what is the *real* question?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: "How to become a Root CA?" (obviously a trusted one, such as LetsEncrypt, Symantec, Digicert and many others). Please provide a solution and let me decide if it's expensive or not.

Comment: What do you think a "Root CA" is? I answered the question that was asked and each link is directly relevant. I'm a Root CA myself, but getting my certs trusted would mean going through the steps linked to (at least 9 years ago it would)

Answer (score 5):

According to 
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/policy/InclusionPolicy.html
(access date: June 2013) it is possible for anyone to become a CA FOR FREE.

Once You get Your certificate bundled with the browser, You are technically as trusted as it gets, in the same league with VeriSign and major banks.

The hard part is, probably, fulfilling all the requirements.

Comment: You're trusted till, like that Dutch CA, you get hacked. Then you're in for damages and lawsuits. Resource allocation to maintain that trust will be extremely necessary and that will be one of the requirements.